# Garageband 10.3 learn to play lessons playing previous attempts when I record another one

Tags: garageband

I recently upgraded to the latest release of Garageband (10.3.2) and when I try to play a piano lesson, I can hear my previous attempt played back to me as I try again. This is very distracting. The only way around it I have found is to record a blank run, listening to my previous mistakes, in between each real attempt.

I've tried turning down each of the channels in the mixer, but the previous recording of myself is on the same channel as the current practise. Is this a known bug in 10.3.2, or is there a setting to switch this off?

Comment: I believe this bug has been there for a long time. I have submitted a bug report though their [feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/garageband.html). I'll report back here when I receive a reply.